# xpath-selecting link by text

Tags: html, xpath, selector

The HTML has a link as below:

```
<a class="alk" href="https://www.xyz.com/view?id=20221">my_color ⁄ color</a>
```

I am able to select it as:

```
//a[@class='alk']
```

and I want to be more definitive and select it as (since there could be more links as this):

```
//a[@class='alk'][text()='my_color ⁄ color']
```

The second selector is not returning me anything. Interestingly, the selector **//a[@class='alk']/text()** does return  **my_color ⁄ color**. I am quite perplexed at what I may be missing in the selector above when trying to select by exact text().

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the whole link, you can adjust your XPath to

```
//a[@class='alk'][text()='my_color ⁄ color']
```

Result:

```
<a class="alk" href="https://www.xyz.com/view?id=20221">my_color ⁄ color</a>
```

The text is not an attribute, so the @ is not needed.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo above. Fixed it. It is not working just with text().

Comment: @naspras Don't mind the typo. That's strange, I had it tested before I posted on www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html and there it's working. Is there possibly any whitespace before/after the link text? If so, this could be fixed using `normalize-space(text())` instead of just `text()`. If not, then it would be good to know in which setting the XPath doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it with the actual URL in www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html and I got a parsing error in the href. The href is correct, but somehow the xpath parser is not able to resolve it. I believe there is something non-standard that is causing it. I will close the question, since I cannot share the actual URL.

Comment: @naspras Thanks for the info, and good luck for solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. FirePath is not able to resolve the xpath, but it does work perfectly fine with the application. I believe something is wrong with the FirePath xpath parser that is sometimes unable to resolve a "valid" xpath expression as this.